# How to reliably wait for an index to be ready in mongodb with the node.js driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Let's say I have a feature in my application which relies on an index to be fully functional to work properly.

For example a unique index which guards against creating duplicates.

Is there a way to find out if the indexes are ready for a specific collection **using the mongodb Node.js driver** ?

Ideally I would like to write a function with this contract

```
async function waitForIndexes(collection:Collection):Promise<void>
```

I found that it's possible to use admin commands to poll background tasks and see it one of them corresponds to an index creation, but that seems a bit tricky to implement in a reliable way. Is there a better way ?

Comment: NodeJS Driver `Collection` has methods to get the information about already existing indexes: `indexExists`, `indexInformation` and `indexes`

Comment: It's bad practice creating indexes on demand since it locks collections (impacting your application), has very high cost (replica set, sharding) and not always is possible(2 o more arrays, exceed key size, etc..). Such indexes should be created manually / controlled. Also, indexes can be created with `background:true` option and there is no way to know if MongoDB has finished it or not

Comment: @Valijon `background` option is ignored since v4.4 or even earlier. Indexing locks only indexed collection and only at start and end of indexing. The way to check status of the process and it's completion is very well documented at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/#active-indexing-operations     It's  `db.currentOp()`  in the shell or `db.command({"currentOp":....})` in nodejs.  Indexing is happening on all members or repset  in parallel.  There were some problems with re-election during indexing, so extra attention to the process is required indeed.